# Circular Queue Simulation

Tags: c, queue

I have made circular queue and through it, i have made a simulation which will enque and dqueue elements from the array. And in the output it will show us the time, customer no. and time last.
But in my output customer no. is repeating again or it contains some junk value, here's the screenshot.
[image]

here's my code.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
//CQUEUE

struct CQueueADT
{
    int head, tail, capacity;
    int data[50];
};


void init(struct CQueueADT *S)
{
    S->capacity=50;
    S->head=0;
    S->tail=0;
}


bool isEmpty(struct CQueueADT *S)
{
    if (S->head==S->tail)
        return true;

    return false;
}

bool isFull(struct CQueueADT *S)
{
    if(S->head==(S->tail+1)%S->capacity)
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool Enque(struct CQueueADT *S, int num)
{
    if(isFull(S))
        return false;
    else
    {
        S->data[S->tail]= num;
        S->tail= (S->tail+1)%(S->capacity);
    }
}
//Dequeue

bool Deque(struct CQueueADT *S, int *num)
{
    if(isFull(S))
        return false;
    else{
        *num = S->data[S->head];
        S->head= (S->head+1)%(S->capacity);
        return true;
    }
}


void SimulateCustomersLine(int min){
    struct CQueueADT CQ;
    init(&CQ);
    int minutes;
    int k;
    int customers = 0;
    int last_time = 0;
    int wait = 0;
    int position = 1;
    for(minutes =0; minutes<min; minutes++){
        printf("%d minutes\n", minutes );
        if(isEmpty(&CQ) == false){
            printf("Dequeuing customer %d\n", position);
            Deque(&CQ, &position);
            wait = customers/100;
            printf("customer %d stayed %d minutes and lasted %d minutes\n", position, wait, last_time);

        }
    // For random number
    k = rand()%4;
    printf("Random number is %d\n", k);
    if(k == 1){
        (customers ++);
        //last_time = (customers % 100);
        printf("Enqueuing customer %d at %d minutes\n", customers,minutes);
        Enque(&CQ, customers);
    }

    else if(k  == 2){
        (customers ++);
        last_time = ( customers % 100);
        printf("Enqueuing customer %d at %d minutes\n", customers,minutes);
        Enque(&CQ, customers);
        (customers ++);
        last_time = (customers % 100);
        printf("Enqueuing customer %d at %d minutes again\n", customers,minutes);
        Enque(&CQ, customers);
    }

    else{
        printf("No customer added at %d minute\n\n", minutes);
    }
    last_time = customers;
    customers = customers + 1;
}


}

int main(){
 int mins;
 struct CQueueADT CQ;
 init(&CQ);
 printf("Enter how many minutes of data you want? ");
 scanf("%d", &mins);
 printf("\n\n");
 SimulateCustomersLine(mins);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to use a debugger, and how to step through your code line by line. That will help you narrow down and maybe even find the problem on your own.

Comment: You're checking `isFull` in both `Enque` and `Deque`.

Comment: You are Calling Dequeue after calling the printf() function. The variable "position" is being set by the Dequeue but printf is printing the previous element which was "Dequeued".

Comment: A circular buffer is much easier to manage if you maintain a variable giving the number of elements in the buffer. Then you don't get any confusion between full or empty buffer conditions.

Comment: ...which you might get by comparing the head and the tail.